# Не работает крос доменный запрос на клиенте

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, https

Когда я делаю запрос на другой домен , то не проходит запрос. Использую XMLHttpRequest.

Вот такая ошибка вылетает в консоли chrome:

> Failed to load [https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00XU2I36S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XU2I36S): No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17777' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: Все верно, принимающая сторона заблокировала внешние запросы и ваш ресурс не находится в белом списке Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Решить можно, но через костыль.

Comment: Возможно ли как то обойти данную проблему?

Comment: @Александ, это не является проблемой. А обойти можно только двумя способами: либо отправляя запросы из расширения браузера (с соотв. правилами в его манифесте); либо используя проксирующий серверный скрипт, который будет качать трафик через себя, и переписывать заголовки ответа (есть публичные сервисы типа https://cors.io, которые реализуют второй подход, но они практически постоянно перегружены).

Comment: У Amazon же вроде есть апи для получения сведений о товарах...  почему не использовать его?